# Searching for numeric values and conditions in text file (Python)

Tags: python, math, text, text-files, conditional-statements

I have a text file with the following format:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Name=A     Run=true     Idle=15     
Name=B     Run=true     Idle=10
Name=C     Run=false    Idle=75
Name=D     Run=true     Idle=92
Name=E     Run=false    Idle=6
Name=F     Run=false    Idle=21

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to search this text file for a run condition of "true" AND an idle of greater than a set value (lets say 10 for example). Once this condition is met, I want to print the whole line. How can I obtain this? The current code is:

```
def main():
  with open('data.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
      if ("Run=true") in line:
        if ("Idle>=10") in line:
          print "\n"
          print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Just updated post with current code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
def main():
  with open('data.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
      line = line.strip()
      # This works because Python checks this substring in the line
      if ("Run=true") in line:
        firstSplit = line.split("Idle=")[1]
        # Splitting again to get the first element before the whitespace
        idleNum = int(firstSplit.split('\s')[0])
        # This had to be changed as you are comparing integers while
        # the data is still of type string
        if (idleNum >=10):
          print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Result using data above:

```
Name=A     Run=true     Idle=15
Name=B     Run=true     Idle=10
Name=D     Run=true     Idle=92
```

Comment: Now I'm running into another problem. There is actually more data in my text file but the Run and Idle values are the only ones I care about. When I compile and run the program, I get the following error. IdleNum = int(line.split("Idle=")[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '0

Comment: Changed according to what you said. I have assumed that your columns are separated by whitespace. If that is true, this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Almost ... let's get to that innermost if ...
At this point, you need to extract the value:

```
field_list = line.split(' ')
```

field list is now a list of three strings, the space-separated fields.  Now, grab the last one and split on the equals sign:

```
idle_field = field_list[-1].split('=')
```

idle_field now contains two strings: "Idle" and the number.  Finally:

```
if int(idle_field) >= 10:
    print "\n", line
```

There's your required condition.

It is possible to fold all that processing into the if condition, but I recommend keeping the program readable.  :-)

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense now.

Comment: @Sahil M Now I'm running into another problem. There is actually more data in my text file but the Run and Idle values are the only ones I care about. When I compile and run the program, I get the following error. IdleNum = int(line.split("Idle=")[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '0

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare an integer by searching for it in a string. Try this

```
import re

def main():   
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if ("Run=true") in line:
                    if int(re.findall(r"Idle=(.+)", line)[0]) >= 10:
                        print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```